# Light ejected orthogonal to direction of motion

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

My understanding of relativity is that light doesn't carry the velocity of its sender. This means that if two objects are traveling at the same speed in parallel directions and light is shot from one object to the other, the light will

1. Potentially miss the targeted object.
2. The reflected light will again potentially miss the initial sender.

How does radar work considering the earth is moving in space at I assume to be a high rate of speed?

Comment: How do you understand the light clock demonstration of time dilation if you think light doesn't have a component of velocity in the direction of the velocity of the sender? If there is a frame in which source and target are at rest to one another then it must also be the case that the light moves from source to target in any other inertial frame.

Comment: Earth moves very very slow relative to the speed of light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong, and a common misconception.

The speed of light is constant, but its direction, and therefore its velocity, is frame dependent.

Suppose the two objects moving in parallel directions are the two sides of a railway carriage. Suppose I stand against one wall and aim a laser at a spot marked on the other wall directly across from me so the laser strikes the wall at 90 degrees. In my frame, the light is pointing at 90 degrees to the railway tracks. From the perspective of a muon passing along the tracks at 0.9999c, the laser is taking an angled path between the tracks, almost at 45 degrees. The laser doesn't miss the spot at which I have pointed it just because the walls of the train are moving at 0.9999c in the frame of the muon.

Comment: I see, I will need to read about the mathematical formulation of special relativity.  The term of "fixed speed" doesn't really work IMO, since it implies an objective frame of reference which doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, where does the phrase 'fixed speed' occur?

Comment: I'm saying in general people say the speed of light is constant which implies to me an objective frame of reference(which is not true I see).

Answer (score 0):

If light is reflected from a moving object the frequency of the light  changes: The speed of the objected can thus be determined. Just read about the [Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_radar)

Answer (score 0):

There're two aspects to your question.

**First**: Compared to light speed, the Earth's velocity is trifling. The Earth moves around the Sun at [about](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/41-our-solar-system/the-earth/orbit/91-at-what-speed-does-the-earth-move-around-the-sun-beginner) $107,000 km/h$, which sounds tremendous, except the speed of light is $1,080,000,000 km/h$. That's three orders of magnitude faster than the Earth's speed.

This means that if we, e.g., attempt to bounce light off the Moon, we can reasonably approximate the Earth as stationary, although we will of course have to aim our laser at where the Moon will be in a second (the Moon is a light second away from the Earth).

Caveat: although the speed of light sounds tremendous, when it comes to astronomical distances it will still usually take a significant amount of time for light to reflect off celestial bodies. So e.g. if we attempt to bounce light off Mars, we will have to take into account the motion of the Earth in addition to the motion of Mars.

**Second**: radar as it is usually used are on other terrestrial objects. In this case it makes no sense to consider the reference frame where the Sun is at rest; one should use the reference frame in which the Earth is at rest. In this reference frame the Earth's motion through space is irrelevant, and the thrust of your question becomes moot.

Answer (score -1):

A flash of light from the source will spread through space at the speed of light (c) in all directions. This expanding sphere may never reach a target on a parallel path.

If you model 4D space-time in 3D, then the sphere is a light cone whose axis lies in the t direction at an angle of 45º  - anything outside the cone is space-like (ie. never reached), inside the cone is time-like.

This also applies to the target - any historic light emission may lie within the negative light cone or not.

So the inertial frame of source and target can be the same, or different. No medium of space (such as the "ether") is needed.

Radar works because even a hypersonic missile (3000 m/s ?) is at snails pace compared to the speed of light (0.001% ish).